# Results from a select passed to an insert in a Stored Proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, select, insert

I'm trying to make a SP that will find the ArticleType (pkey I forgot to put ID on it) from another table based on the ArticleTypeName supplied and use that to insert into the new category in the categories table. Finally the new row's ID is sent back in an output param. I thought everything was correct but I keep getting an error stating that the syntax is incorrect around 'Insert'. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple!

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE InsertCategory
        @ParentCatID int,
        @CategoryName varchar(25),
        @ArticleTypeName varchar(15),
        @NewCategoryID int OUTPUT

    AS
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @ArticleType int

    SELECT @ArticleType=ArticleType
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1 ArticleType FROM ArticleTypes
        WHERE (ArticleTypeName=@ArticleTypeName))

    INSERT INTO Categories (ParentCatID, CategoryName, ArticleType) VALUES (@ParentCatID, @CategoryName, @ArticleType)

    SET @NewCategoryID = Scope_Identity()
    END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subquery requires an alias.  For example, this will give an error:

```
select * from (select id from MyTable)
```

But this will work:

```
select * from (select id from MyTable) as SubQueryAlias
```

So in your case, add the alias at this point:

```
FROM (
        SELECT TOP 1 ArticleType FROM ArticleTypes
        WHERE (ArticleTypeName=@ArticleTypeName)) as SubQueryName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using SELECT to set identity instead of using SET

```
SELECT @NewCategoryID = Scope_Identity()
```